# rpyc : subprocess doesn’t work. it throws error : specified file not found

Tags: python, rpyc

I am using RpYC to execute commands on remote machine. When I run the below mentioned code, I get error message stated below:

Error:

```
>>> c = rpyc.classic.connect("server1")

>>> proc = c.modules.subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout = -1, stderr = -1)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__

    return syncreq(_self, consts.HANDLE_CALL, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq

    return conn.sync_request(handler, oid, *args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 441, in sync_request

    raise obj

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: None

 

========= Remote Traceback (1) =========

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 305, in _dispatch_request

    res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 535, in _handle_call

    return self._local_objects[oid](*args, **dict(kwargs))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__

    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child

    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Error at Server side:

```
C:\Users\hemanth>python C:\Python27\Scripts\rpyc_classic.py

INFO:SLAVE/18812:server started on [0.0.0.0]:18812

INFO:SLAVE/18812:accepted client1:54680

INFO:SLAVE/18812:welcome [client1]:54680

DEBUG:SLAVE/18812:Exception caught

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 305, in _dispatch_request

    res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 535, in _handle_call

    return self._local_objects[oid](*args, **dict(kwargs))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__

    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child

    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: give the full path for the file

Comment: First of all you should properly format the code / trackebacks in your question, this is horrible to read.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087375/subprocess-call-with-rpyc-throwing-error/32087432#32087432. May be useful for you