# subprocess.call with rpyc throwing error

Tags: python, subprocess, rpyc

I am using RPyc to execute commands on remote machine. I am getting error when I run the following code:

```
cmd = ['clonetst.exe', 'C:\\Users\\pqalinux\\Desktop\\Flowcontrol.tst', 'C:\\Users\\pqalinux\\Desktop\\lst_20150819_110008.lst', 'C:\\Users\\pqalinux\\Desktop\\tst_20150819_110008.tst']
self.host = rpyc.classic.connect(self.ip)
StatusCode = self.host.modules.subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

The remote traceback is:

```
Failed to create tst file: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified

========= Remote Traceback (1) =========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 305, in _dispatch_request
    res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 535, in _handle_call
    return self._local_objects[oid](*args, **dict(kwargs))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 507, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 494, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 675, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 887, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _subprocess.CreateProcess(executable, args,
WindowsError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What might be the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try specifying the full path to `clonetst.exe`? It looks like the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either 'clonetst.exe' is not installed on the remote machine or it is neither on the `path` nor in the current directory. Make sure it is installed and either add to the `path` permanently or in the environment dictionaries.